# Fractal design for svg file

Tags: python, python-2.7, turtle-graphics

I'm very new to coding and I am attempting to create a box svg file with a fractal spiral design on one of the box wings. I'm having a difficult time with this and I'm hoping someone can offer some guidance as to where I'm going wrong.

Here is part of my code:

```
import turtle

def spiral(x, y):

    spiral1 = turtle.setpos({},{})

    return spiral1.format(x,y)

    t = turtle.Turtle()
    t.pensize(1)
    t.pencolor('orange')
    t.speed(0)
    for i in range (10):
        t.circle(10 + i, 45)

spiral_1 = spiral(int(box_x)*96, int(box_height)*96)
```

this is giving me an error:unsupported operand type(s) for * 'dict' and 'float'

Essentially what I want to do is write this spiral onto my actual svg file which has specific coordinates I've already defined (i.e box_height)). I'm not quite sure where to go from here. I'd really appreciate your help.

Edit: perhaps I need to figure out how to generate the pattern with svg code rather than turtle

Answer (score 1):

> I'm hoping someone can offer some guidance as to where I'm going wrong

I'm having a hard time figuring out where you went *right*:

```
spiral1 = turtle.setpos({},{})
```

This doesn't appear to be Python argument syntax and `setpos()` always returns `None` so there's no point in saving the result into `spiral1`.

```
return spiral1.format(x,y)
```

`None` doesn't have a `format()` method.  Also, the `return` at this point in the code causes it to ignore the next six lines of code.  Effectively, not drawing at all.

```
spiral_1 = spiral(int(box_x)*96, int(box_height)*96)
```

`spiral()` doesn't return anything useful, so no point saving the result.  Let's rework your code so that it actually draws a spiral:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

box_x, box_y = 96, 96

def spiral(x, y):

    turtle.penup()
    turtle.setposition(x, y)
    turtle.pendown()

    for i in range(100):
        turtle.circle(10 + i, 45)

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.pencolor('orange')
turtle.speed('fastest')

spiral(box_x, box_y)

screen.exitonclick()
```

I don't see why this question is tagged [fractals].  Nor do I see why it's tagged [xml] and [svg] as it's a simple Python syntax and turtle graphics question.  And you really shouldn't be getting started with Python 2.7 as it is no longer supported.

[image]

Comment: It seems that they are want to produce a svg file. And turtle graphics might look like a possible way to do that.